# How to disable the main splitbutton action, but keep enabled the arrow

Tags: button, extjs4, split-button

I have a split button and i want, for some cases, to disable main button action but keep the arrow for viewing the menu.
Is there any change to do this? I think that maybe i have to create two buttons,

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to check if the action is allowed or not in the button handler, and set it in your flow..
Here is a working fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bv8
There could be other / better options but this should work.
Hope it helps.